# How to add data to hash set in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, hashmap, hashset

I have a set of hashmap (or a hashset, an array of hashmaps) like below:

```
(def mydata #{{:rank 2 :page 1 :group "fish"}
              {:rank 1 :page 1 :group "mammal"}
              {:rank 3 :page 2 :group "bird"}})
```

and I have a new hashmap like this:

```
{:group "mammal" :name "lion" :score 566}
```

What I want to do basically is to sort of merge that new hashmap data into the above array, so it would look like this ('group' is the join key):

```
#{{:rank 2 :page 1 :group "fish"}
  {:rank 1 :page 1 :group "mammal" :name "lion" :score 566}
  {:rank 3 :page 2 :group "bird"}}
```

My idea is to first find the index in the array which is 1 (zero-based) and then use assoc-in function with that new hashmap given so 'group' gets ignored or stays the same, and 'name' and 'score' are added.

First, I need to find a way to get that index but that's where I'm stuck now.

Is there any simple and easy way of doing this? Finished data will get converted to json.

(I'm not even sure if building an array of hashmaps like this is a correct way   of making some json data in Clojure. At least, passing a set of hashmaps to json library works for now which generates an array of data sets in json format, but please give some advise if I'm going in a wrong way.)

Comment: Your data structure allows for only one animal in each group. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. it is like a 1:1 join key in a RDB schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all the hash set doesn't give you any profit in this usecase (any sequence will do, and any sequence would be converted to json array, based on what i know about json libs in clojure)

but is the kind of operation you describe is rather frequent, and/or the collection can be large, it is quite expensive to do it by traversing the whole coll every time. I would reformat your data to a map indexed by group:

```
(def mydata {"fish" {:rank 2 :page 1 :group "fish"}
             "mammal" {:rank 1 :page 1 :group "mammal"}
             "bird" {:rank 3 :page 2 :group "bird"}})
```

and then update it like this:

```
(defn update-animal [animal data]
  (update data (:group animal) merge animal))


user> (update-animal {:group "mammal" :name "lion" :score 566} mydata)
;;{"fish" {:rank 2, :page 1, :group "fish"}, 
;; "mammal" {:rank 1, :page 1, :group "mammal", :name "lion", :score 566}, 
;; "bird" {:rank 3, :page 2, :group "bird"}}
```

and when you need to convert it to json, you just take the values sequence:
`(to-json (vals data))`

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not have indices. You can iterate all of its elements and if any one matches the new hashmap then replace it with a merged hasmap (the existing element and the new one). Finally convert the result to a set.

```
(defn update-set 
  [baseset elem] 
  (set (map #(if (= (:group elem) (:group %)) 
                 (merge elem %) 
                 %1) 
            baseset)))


(def mydata #{{:rank 2 :page 1 :group "fish"}
            {:rank 1 :page 1 :group "mammal"}
            {:rank 3 :page 2 :group "bird"}})

(update-set mydata {:group "mammal" :name "lion" :score 566})
```